# PC Lags after some Android Studio Flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, android-studio, crash, lag

Here are my PC Specs

- Acer Aspire 5
- Intel Core i3-8145U 2.1GHz with Turbo Boost up to 3.9GHz
- RAM: 4GB DDR4
- SSD: Kingston SUV500M8120G
- OS: Windows 10

So I watched flutter tutorials...
I tried to do it with Android Studio... I installed it in hdd...
So I didn't care too much about the ram usage and the lag...

Two or three days ago, when the emulator was running, *the machine suddenly froze*...
After waiting for half an hour, I tried to get the task manager but it didn't, so I turned it off with the power button...

After that, I googled and said that it is difficult to run an emulator with my pc specs...
So I used my phone that day and connected it with a data cable...

Anyway, since the day of that freeze, ***the lap is slower than before***...
The file explorer and also After pressing the windows key, it takes a while to open...

**What is the reason for this**???

I use Eset Internet Security...
I did a full scan of it and nothing...

I also tried the chkdsk command on all three partitions and there is no problem...

When I used Angular before, I used Webstrom...
It's not that bad as android studio, it wasn't slow...

---

Should I reset the pc???
There is no big case because only the software are uninstalled.....​​

Or should I install the android studio on the ssd...​

The problem I have is that even after closing the android studio, it lags...
Even after restarting the PC, it is the same

Tell me some solution guys, it's a big help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to have good about of ram, 16 GB is good, less 8 GB might feel laggy.

Android studio consume more than Visual Studio Code. I will suggest you to switch on  VS Code, and upgrading your component, increase the ram. Resetting Pc won't help that much. Try to kill every background process, just use vs-code. If you like to build for android use real device.

As for learning,  you can try on [dart.dev](https://dartpad.dev/)

Comment: Yeah my question is earlier there's no lag of pc like this. Even I didn't open android studio... What would be the reason???

Comment: it could be background service/ temp file. you can explore on `Task Manager`